# zsh: How to retrieve the previous command line?

Tags: command-line, zsh

I would like to create a command which fetches matching previous command, something like this:

```
match-latest "ssh root@150"
```

but which then exits and populates the command prompt with the most recent match, e.g.:

```
owilliams@OWILLIAMS010451 ~/go/ % ssh root@150.2.3.4
```

and leaves it for the user to edit (if desired) and press enter themself.  Is this possible?  How would I do it?

I am using `zsh` 5.8 on a MacBook Pro OSX

Comment: you mean like pressing CTRL+r and then typing letters?

Comment: actually yest that appears to do it.  At first I thought it might only cover the current session but it appears to grab former sessions also

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) offers a plethora of ways to retrieve command lines from history. Here’s just a selection of these.

### Keybindings

- Press <kbd>↑</kbd> to step through previous command lines.
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to step through the *last word* of each previous command line.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (“reverse”) and start typing to *search* through previous command lines.
- Type a word at the start of a new command line and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (“previous”) to step through previous lines *starting* with that word.

See [*Zsh Line Editor: History Control*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#History-Control) in the Zsh manual for more options.

### History expansion

- Type `!!` anywhere on your current command line, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to replace it with the previous command line.
- Type `!<word>` and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to replace it with the most recent command line *starting* with `<word>`.
- Type `!?<word>` and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to replace it with the most recent command line *containing* `<word>`.

See [*History Expansion*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#History-Expansion) in the Zsh manual for more options.

### `fc` builtin command

- Type `fc` (“fix command”) on a new command line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the previous command line in an external editor (configured by setting `$EDITOR`), after which Zsh runs the modified command line.
- Use `fc <word>` for the most recent line *starting* with `<word>`.
- Pass the `-s` (“silently”) flag to execute the line *immediately,* without first editing it.

See [*Shell Builtin Commands: `fc`*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-history_002c-editing) in the Zsh manual for more options.